# Reading mutable objects in a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency

As per the [JavaSE 8 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) on the `ConcurrentHashMap`

> ... even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking....

How does the above play with the `compute` function of the `ConcurrentHashMap` ? Consider the following simple object

```
final class PlainObject{
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

Consider the following mapping

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, PlainObject> myMap;
```

Consider the following function that has access to `myMap`

```
void act(){

  myMap.compute("abc", (k, v) -> {
    v.a = 21;
    // Other work 
    v.b = 18;

    return v;
  });
}
```

Can I ever perform a read on `myMap` that will print a partial result (i.e. only `a` has been modified) ? It seems the answer is yes because retrieving data does not entail locking and we are dealing with a mutable object. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: P.S., I have a comment on how you are using `compute`. See the "update" in my answer (below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The `get()` operation is "thread safe" in the sense that it is guaranteed either to return the `PlainObject` that was present for the given `k` before the map was updated or, return the new object that was added under that `k`. It will never return some other object, or cause a program crash.

**BUT**

The fact that the map itself is thread safe in no way protects the objects that you put *in* the map. If you want your program to see consistent values of `v.a` and `v.b` when one thread wants to examine the object concurrently with some other thread that modifies the object, then that's entirely up to you to provide that protection.

---

**update:**

Your example does not use `compute` in the way it was meant to be used. The function you provide never returns a different `v` from the one that already was in the map. The code that you wrote doesn't do anything different from this version:

```java
void act(){
  PlainObject v = myMap.get("abc");
  if (v != null) {
    v.a = 21;
    // Other work
    v.b = 18;
  }
}
```

The purpose of `compute` is to let you write a function that decides whether or not the object in the map should be replaced with a different object:

```java
void foo() {
  myMap.compute("abc", (k, v) -> {
    if ((v == null) || ...other reason not to update...) {
      return /*the original, UNMODIFIED*/ v;
    }
    else {
      PlainObject new_v = new PlainObject();
      new_v.a = 21;
      // Other work 
      new_v.b = 18;
      return new_v;
    }
  });
```

In this case, if some other thread calls `myMap.get("abc")`, it is guaranteed either to get the original unmodified `PlainObject` or, to get the new object. And, if your `PlainObject` instances are all *effectively immutable,** then the new object already will have been *safely published*† by the time the `get()` function returns it.

* It would be "effectively immutable" if no thread ever modifies a `PlainObject` after the object has been made available to other threads.

† "Safely published" means there is a "happens before" relationship between the initialization of the new object and the first opportunity that any other thread has to access it.